# What is the purpose and code content of Chrome's proxy script?

Tags: google-chrome, proxy

What is the purpose and the **code content** of the "Proxy Script" that Chrome attempts to load every time a new page is loaded?

An easy way to trigger this message is to turn on and off Airplane mode:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This happens when your computer's network settings have a HTTP proxy configured. The [proxy auto-config (PAC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config) script file is specified *in those settings;* Chrome then downloads it and runs it to determine whether and how each request will be proxied. The script is provided by your proxy, not Chrome.

If you are not intentionally using proxies, you should remove the proxy configuration as it might be either unnecessary or malicious. But if this is a machine owned by your employer, it is probably intentional.

I'm not sure if this work the same way on all OSes, but for me on macOS, there's a link from Chrome's settings to the OS network settings:

[image: "System: Open your computer's proxy settings"]

The reason the message pops up when you enter/exit airplane mode is probably because that counts as a change of network configuration (between "no internet (and no proxy)" to "yes internet and also proxy"), and it's making sure it has the latest PAC script.

If you want to find out what the script contains, copy the PAC URL out of your network settings and download it separately; then you can read the code (which is JavaScript).